# cmake: command not found on macOS

Tags: cocoapods, xcode9.4

After adding this line in my Podfile:

```
pod 'PiwikTracker', :git => 'https://github.com/manuroe/matomo-sdk-ios.git', :branch => 'feature/CustomVariables'
```

The below error is occuring:

```
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
echo `pwd`
sed -i '' 's/include <\(cmark.*\)>/include "\1"/' src/cmark.h
mkdir -p build; cd build && cmake -G Xcode ..

/Users/mac1/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/cmark/0.24.1-ec027
/bin/bash: line 4: cmake: command not found
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 83):

Use [Brew](https://brew.sh) to install `cmake`

```
brew install cmake
```

Answer (score 9):

Install Brew

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Use Brew to install `cmake`

```
brew install cmake
```

Answer (score 1):

To use above library you can try as mention below :

You want to add **pod 'PiwikTracker', '~> 4.4'** similar to the following to your Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'PiwikTracker', '~> 4.4'
end
```

Then run a pod install inside your terminal, or from CocoaPods.app.

Alternatively to give it a test run, run the command:

```
pod try PiwikTracker
```

for more detail try this link : [PiwikTracker](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PiwikTracker)

Hope this will helps!