# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MatrixSDK"

Tags: xcode, git, cocoapods, ipa, appium-ios

I'm trying to build application from xcode.
I cloned the project from git repo.
I opened .xcodeproj file and from Product > Build I tried to build but build is failed.
From terminal I executed below commands and receiving compatible version error

**I searched for solution and tried few ways like:**

sudo gem intall cocoapods
sudo gem intall cocoapods --pre
pod setup
pod deintegrate
pod install
pod update
pod install --repo-update

**Below is terminal output:**

```
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `BarcodeScanner` from `https://github.com/htothee/BarcodeScanner.git`
Pre-downloading: `MatrixKit` from `https://github.com/N-Pex/matrix-ios-kit.git`, branch `fix_apns_push`
Pre-downloading: `MatrixSDK` from `https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk.git`, branch `develop`
Pre-downloading: `QRCode` from `https://github.com/brackendev/QRCode.git`
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MatrixSDK":
  In Podfile:
    MatrixKit (from `https://github.com/N-Pex/matrix-ios-kit.git`, branch `fix_apns_push`) was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
      MatrixSDK (= 0.13.0)

    MatrixSDK (from `https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk.git`, branch `develop`)
```

**Below is Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '9.3'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'ProjectCore', :path => '../'
    pod 'MatrixKit', :git => 'https://github.com/N-Pex/matrix-ios-kit.git', :branch => 'fix_apns_push'
    pod 'MatrixSDK', :git => 'https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'develop'
end

target 'Project_Example' do
  shared_pods

  pod 'BarcodeScanner', :git => 'https://github.com/htothee/BarcodeScanner.git'
  pod 'QRCode', :git => 'https://github.com/brackendev/QRCode.git'

  pod 'Project', :path => '../'

  target 'Project_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

target 'ShareExtension' do
  shared_pods

  pod 'ProjectExtension', :path => '../'
end
```

**Expected:**
.ipa file need to be created

Please let me know how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is explained in the error:

> [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MatrixSDK":
>     In Podfile:
>       MatrixKit (from `https://github.com/N-Pex/matrix-ios-kit.git`, branch `fix_apns_push`) was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
>         MatrixSDK (= 0.13.0)

The branch `fix_apns_push` of `MatrixKit` needs a fixed version of `MatrixSDK`, as you can see in its [Podspec file](https://github.com/N-Pex/matrix-ios-kit/blob/fix_apns_push/Podfile)

```
pod 'MatrixSDK', '0.13.0'
```

So, In order for your project to work, you need this version.

Try this:

```
def shared_pods
    pod 'ProjectCore', :path => '../'
    pod 'MatrixKit', :git => 'https://github.com/N-Pex/matrix-ios-kit.git', :branch => 'fix_apns_push'
    pod 'MatrixSDK', '0.13.0'
end
```

Comment: Thanks @alxlives, I added MatrixSDK version and dependencies were added but while installing cmark (0.24.1) it failed and got cmake: command not found error. I found same ticket for this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52531492/cmake-command-not-found and tried **pod try PiwikTracker** but no luck

Comment: Nevermind it worked using brew install cmake command. Thanks and appreciate your efforts!

Comment: Sure I checked it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

same problem for me
**CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Branch"**

remove Podfile.lock and Pods then do pod install

> rm -rf ./Pods Podfile.lock

> pod install --repo-update

try this, this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

insted of projectname.xcodeproj, please try to open projectname.xcworkspace.

Comment: @Jij3r : I opened projectname.xcworkspace and tried to build. But getting Swift Compile Error

Comment: can you please post it ?

Comment: Please delete the project and try to clone the project , and again try to open projectname.xcworkspace then try to build it